# Java MineSweeper console Recursion Error

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, helper, minesweeper

I'm new to Stack overflow.

I have been having trouble with my minesweeper text-based program, and I just can't get my recursion to work in the way I want it to.

Can someone help me with my recursion for revealing all cells that are blank and are neighbors to the "clicked" cell?

The problem with my code is that everytime I reveal a spot within the 10 by 10 board,

***for example:***

when you input r to reveal, and put in the row 3 and column 3

the code reveals all locations of the map excluding the mines,
instead of reveal only the numbers nearby and not connected to other 'blank' locations.

*These are outdated now*

The **output** should be:

```
 1|  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 2|  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 3|  .  .  3  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 4|  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 5|  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 6|  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 7|  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 8|  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
 9|  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
10|  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

However the **actual output** is:

```
 1|  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0 
 2|  1  .  1  1  .  1  0  0  0  0 
 3|  2  3  3  2  2  2  1  0  0  0 
 4|  1  .  .  1  1  .  2  1  1  0 
 5|  1  3  3  2  2  2  3  .  2  1 
 6|  0  2  .  2  1  .  3  3  .  1 
 7|  0  2  .  2  1  1  2  .  2  1 
 8|  1  2  3  2  1  0  1  1  1  0 
 9|  2  .  4  .  1  1  1  2  1  1 
10|  2  .  .  2  1  1  .  2  .  1 
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

**These are my guidelines for recursion:**

Recursive algorithm for minesweeper

When the user clicks on a cell

If the cell hasn't yet been revealed, reveal it

If the true nature of the cell is a mine, game over

Otherwise if the true nature of the cell is blank, then recursively reveal
     each its 8 neighbors if they are within bounds and haven't been revealed.

This algorithm naturally uncovers all adjacent empty cells and terminates when it reaches number cells on the edges.

here is my new **Code**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P4_Icel_Murad_MinesweeperConsole {
     char resp = ' ';
     int row =  0;
     int col = 0;
     final static int MINES = 5;
     public boolean won = false;
     public boolean fail = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        P4_Icel_Murad_MinesweeperConsole hello = new P4_Icel_Murad_MinesweeperConsole(10, MINES);
        System.out.println();
        hello.revealBoard();
    }


        private static class Cell {

            final int FLAGGED = 1;
            final int QUESTION = 2;
            final int BLANK = 3;


            public boolean hidden = true;
            public final boolean mine;
            public int flagType;
            public int neighbors = 0;


            public Cell(boolean mine) {
                this.mine = mine;
            }
            public void setFlag(int myFlagType){
                if(myFlagType == 1){
                    this.flagType = myFlagType;
                }else if (myFlagType == 2) {
                    this.flagType = myFlagType;
                }else if (myFlagType == 3) {
                    hidden = true;
                    this.neighbors = myFlagType;
                }
            }
            public boolean getflagType(int i) {
                if(i == 1){
                    return true;
                }else
                return false;
            }
        }

        private final int size;
        private Cell[][] board;

        private void revealBoard(){
            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
                    Cell f = board[i][j];
                    f.hidden = false;

                }
            }
            showBoard();
        }
        private void revealCell(int i, int j){          
                    Cell f = board[i][j];
                    f.hidden = false;
                    f.setFlag(0);

        }



        private P4_Icel_Murad_MinesweeperConsole(int size, int numberOfMines) {
            this.size = size;
            initBord(numberOfMines);
            showBoard();
            while(!won && !fail){
                questionAsk();
                showBoard();
            }
        }

        private void questionAsk(){
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Would you like to flag a cell or reveal a cell?");
            System.out.println("Enter 'f' or 'r': >");
            resp = s.next().charAt(0);
             System.out.println("Enter row: ");
             row = s.nextInt() - 1;
             System.out.println("Enter col: ");
             col = s.nextInt() - 1;
             if(row > size || col > size){
                 System.out.println("This row/col amount is too high.");
                 showBoard();
                 questionAsk();
             }
             userInput(row,col,true);
        }
        private void initBord(int numberOfMines) {
            List<Cell> mines = new ArrayList<Cell>();
            for (int i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
                mines.add(new Cell(i < numberOfMines));
            }
            Collections.shuffle(mines);
            board = new Cell[size][size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    board[i][j] = (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == size || j == size)
                            ? new Cell(false)
                            : mines.remove(0);
                }
            }
            calculateNeighbors();
        }
        // F>HIDDEN IS DONE ONLY FOR ONE POS, MUST FIX
        private void userInput(int row, int col, boolean revealMines){
            Cell f = board[row][col];
            if (resp == 'r') {
                if (f.mine && !revealMines) {
                    return;
                }
            if (f.hidden) { 
                revealCell(row,col);

                if(f.mine){
                    failed();   
                }else if (f.neighbors == 0){

                        if (isInBounds(row + 1,col)){
                            Cell neighbor = board[row + 1][col];
                            if (neighbor.hidden && neighbor.neighbors == 0) {
                                userInput(row + 1,col,false);
                            }else if (neighbor.hidden && !neighbor.mine){
                                revealCell(row + 1,col);
                            }
                        }
                        if (isInBounds(row - 1,col)){
                            Cell neighbor = board[row - 1][col];
                            if (neighbor.hidden && neighbor.neighbors == 0) {
                                userInput(row - 1,col,false);
                            }else if (neighbor.hidden && !neighbor.mine){
                                revealCell(row - 1,col);
                            }
                        }
                        if (isInBounds(row,col - 1)){
                            Cell neighbor = board[row][col - 1];
                            if (neighbor.hidden && neighbor.neighbors == 0) 
                            userInput(row,col - 1,false);
                            else if (neighbor.hidden && !neighbor.mine){
                                revealCell(row,col-1);
                            }
                        }
                        if (isInBounds(row , col + 1)){
                            Cell neighbor = board[row][col + 1];
                            if (neighbor.hidden && neighbor.neighbors == 0) 
                            userInput(row,col + 1,false);   
                            else if (neighbor.hidden && !neighbor.mine){
                                revealCell(row,col+1);
                            }
                        }
                        if (isInBounds(row - 1,col - 1)){
                            Cell neighbor = board[row - 1][col - 1];
                            if (neighbor.hidden && neighbor.neighbors == 0) 
                            userInput(row - 1,col - 1,false);
                            else if (neighbor.hidden && !neighbor.mine){
                                revealCell(row -1 ,col - 1);
                            }
                        }
                        if (isInBounds(row + 1,col - 1)){
                            Cell neighbor = board[row + 1][col - 1];
                            if (neighbor.hidden && neighbor.neighbors == 0) 
                            userInput(row + 1,col - 1,false);
                            else if (neighbor.hidden && !neighbor.mine){
                                revealCell(row + 1 ,col - 1);
                            }
                        }
                        if (isInBounds(row + 1,col + 1)){
                            Cell neighbor = board[row + 1][col + 1];
                            if (neighbor.hidden && neighbor.neighbors == 0) 
                            userInput(row + 1,col + 1,false);
                            else if (neighbor.hidden && !neighbor.mine){
                                revealCell(row + 1 ,col + 1);
                            }
                        }
                        if (isInBounds(row - 1,col + 1) && f.hidden){
                            Cell neighbor = board[row - 1][col + 1];
                            if (neighbor.hidden && neighbor.neighbors == 0) 
                            userInput(row - 1,col + 1,false);   
                            else if (neighbor.hidden && !neighbor.mine){
                                revealCell(row - 1 ,col + 1);
                            }
                        }

                }

            }
            }
            if(resp == 'f'){
                if (f.hidden) {
                    f.setFlag(1);
                    revealCell(row,col);

                }else if(f.flagType == 1){
                    f.setFlag(2);
                }else if(f.flagType == 2){
                    f.setFlag(3);
                }else if(f.flagType == 3){
                    f.setFlag(1);
                }

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
                if(f.getflagType(1) == f.mine)
                    won = true;
                }
            }



                }



        private boolean isInBounds(int row, int col){
            if((row < size && row >= 0) && (col < size && col >= 0)){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }



        private void failed(){
            System.out.println("You Lost! :(");
            fail = true;
        }


        private void calculateNeighbors() {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {            
                    for (int di = -1; di <= 1; di++) {
                        for (int dj = -1; dj <= 1; dj++) {
                            if(isInBounds(i + di,j + dj))
                                if (board[i + di][j + dj].mine) count++;  
                        }
                    }
                    board[i][j].neighbors = count;
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

        }

        private void showBoard() {
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                System.out.printf("%2d| ",i + 1);
               for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                   Cell f = board[i][j];
                   if(f.hidden || f.flagType == 3) {
                       System.out.printf("%3s",". ");
                   }  else if (f.mine) {
                       System.out.printf("%3s","* ");
                   } else if (f.flagType == 1){
                       System.out.printf("%3s","F ");
                   }else if (f.flagType == 2){
                       System.out.printf("%3s","? ");
                   }else{
                       calculateNeighbors();
                       System.out.printf("%3s", f.neighbors + " ");
                   }
               }          
               System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.print("    ");
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                System.out.printf("%3s",i + 1 + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }





Thank you in advance.
```

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: @AndyTurner everytime I try to reveal the cell's contents, it recursively reveals everything, which causes it to lose because a mine has been revealed.

Comment: @AndyTurner I changed my question to fit better to the requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass a boolean to your `userInput` function indicating whether or not to reveal mines. If the function is called with actual user input, you should pass true, because the mine should be revealed and it should be game over. If the function is called recursively, pass false, because you only want to recursively reveal empty cells.

Test like this:

```
private void userInput(int row, int col, boolean revealMines){
    Cell f = board[row][col];
    if (resp == 'r') {

        // if this cell is a mine and we are not revealing mines, return:
        if (f.mine && !revealMines)
            return;

        if (f.hidden) {
```

Call like this in the `questionAsk` function:

```
 userInput(row,col,true);
```

and false when called recursively.

Comment: This works for the most part, however when I input a position that includes a number within the cell, the cell recursively reveals everything else as well.

Comment: for example if I try to reveal the position 3,3 then it reveals every blank and numbered cell within the board as well.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to recursively reveal along diagonals? That will reveal cells quite aggressively. Perhaps if you only reveal cells left, right, above and below it will produce the behaviour you want.

Comment: You're using the neighbors variable for a count of the number of mines in neighboring cells, but you're also using it for the flag type. Is that correct?

Comment: I want to do diagonal as well, as that is how the minesweeper game is played.

Comment: the flag type is for flagging the cell as either F or ? symbols

Comment: I mean this line: `this.neighbors = myFlagType;`

Comment: Try calling `calculateNeighbors()` from your `initbord()` function, to make sure the values are initialized properly

Comment: ok that allowed for the recursion to work better, now all I need to do is reveal the numbers that are stopping the recursion

Comment: could we discuss this in chat?

Comment: Here's a hint: after the `if (neighbor.hidden && neighbor.neighbors == 0)` test, add an else condition and reveal the cell if it meets certain criteria. I can explain in chat but give it a try first.

Comment: so is it a else if statement or an else statement, as I applied an else statement to all of them to reveal their locations but it gave an error

Comment: It seems I don't have the reputation to chat yet

Comment: an else if statement after each individual test. you need to reveal it if it's hidden and not a mine, but don't recurse if it has 1 or more neighbours that are mines

Comment: ok that worked, now I have one more question, when I try to flag a cell, it cycles through the F ? and blank symbols, however, when I try to reveal the cell again, it will reveal a question mark (?), is there any way I can fix that?

Comment: clear the flag type in your revealCell function when you reveal a cell

Comment: so should I set the flag to int 0?

Comment: Look at the logic inside your showBoard function

Comment: I replaced my old code in the question with my new code, I don't understand how to fix it

Comment: setFlag(0) isn't going to do anything because setFlag doesn't handle the case where myFlagType is 0

Comment: ok thank you, i figured it out